# "Please wait while Windows configures Microsoft Visual Studio 2008"

Tags: visual-studio, installation, build-process

I get the message "Please wait while Windows configures Microsoft Visual Studio 2008..." whenever I build the install project for my application. It configures VS for a while, then builds the project. This does not happen when I build the vb.net application itself, only the installation project in the same solution. This occurs on applications using the Leadtools library, but not others.

Any ideas on what could cause this?

Comment: I uninstalled then reinstalled VS and the problem went away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio and the problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this website (because I am afraid that it might go away):

http://zw-byteme.blogspot.com/2017/02/vb6-startup-annoyance-please-wait-while.html
[image]

VB6 startup annoyance: 'Please wait while Windows configures Microsoft Visual Studio 2010'
If you are still maintaining old VB6 code and have newer versions of Visual Studio installed, you may be dealing with this annoyance every time you launch your IDE:

What is happening is there is an installed VS.NET component referenced in your system registry which itself references xml configuration files which may or may not exist on your system - even if the installation of that component has been successful.  When one of these xml files is not found, Windows Installer kicks in and tries to "fix" things.  Uh thanks MS.  Of course VB6 itself does not care about any of these xml files.

Fortunately, creating zero byte files with the paths and names it is expecting should make the problem go away.  To find the names of the missing files, open your Event Viewer (just type "Event Viewer" in the Windows search bar or go to Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools > Event Viewer) and navigate to Windows Logs > Application.  You should see a pair of yellow triangle "Warning" icons attributed to Windows Installer near the top of the list - the missing file will be shown in the first (lower) of the two events.

[image]

Create that missing file and run VB6 again.  Refresh the Event Viewer and look for the next missing file, create it, etc. until the error no longer appears.

Note that due to folder security settings, it is probably easiest to create each file in a location which you have full access to (e.g. your Desktop) and then copy the new file into the destination folder.

The missing file names themselves may vary, but this is what I had to create to solve the error with VS 2010:

You can simply create empty .txt files and rename them and put them where the event viewer looks for them.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\System.Windows.xml
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Vsa.xml
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5.xml
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\en\Microsoft.ManagementConsole.xml
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\en\System.Configuration.Install.xml
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RedistList\VSList.xml